# Preload Attributes of my entity

Tags: magento

guys.

How i can preload eav attributes of some entity? like:

Want preload attributes of the customers programmatically? Or programmatically my product catalog?

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean by 'preload' ?
You can easily load any attribute by just calling loadByCode:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', '%attribute_code%')
```

Or, you can load *all* attributes using collection:

```
$entityType          = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('catalog_product');
$attributeCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
```

there are 8 entity types in magento:

1. customer
2. customer_address
3. catalog_category
4. catalog_product
5. order
6. invoice
7. creditmemo
8. shipment

Comment: There are several more entity types than that - ref `eav_entity_type` table.